# Reading files from a folder in a class library

Tags: c#, file-access

I'm having a brain fart at the moment.  I have a set of files that are read in by a class library in a .NET Web Site.  The issue is the files are used in three different sites (all the sites reference the class library), so I don't want to copy the files across all three.  What I want to do is have a folder in the class library itself as a shared resource, something like this:

```
ClassLib
  \Templates
    -file1.xml
    -file2.pdf
  -MyClass.cs
```

and have MyClass read the files from the Templates directory.  Easy enough, except that MyClass.cs is called from a page, let's call it Default.aspx.  Now MyClass.cs has code like the following:

```
IList<string> files = GetTemplateFiles(); // returns the path to the template files e.g. Templates/file1.xml
foreach (string file in files) { 
    if (File.Exists(file)) { 
        // do things here...
    }
}
```

File.Exists is always false, seemingly because it is looking in the default directory and not the path to ClassLib (which is something like `C:\Projects\Shared\MyLib\`).  Now, I cannot use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` because this varies based on the web site which is calling it; the templates should **always** be available from the Templates directory in the class library, not the calling application.  The properties in `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` don't seem to be of much help either, pointing to ASP.NET Temporary Files.

Basically my question is what the best way to handle this would be.  The template files should be a shared resource available to every application (and not copy/pasted into three Templates/ directories in each application), but I don't know which application will call it at a given time so I need to avoid hard-coding the file path to the templates folder.  I'm missing something small but critical in how I'm trying to retrieve the template file, but I can't figure out exactly what.

Comment: How about a config file in each of the applications that are using the templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide on a common, shared path available to all three sites and define that path in your web.config files, making sure that IIS is able to access that shared folder.

Comment: Config file, of course!  I knew I was forgetting something simplistic!

Comment: You said it yourself; "I'm having a brain fart at the moment". That's what SO is for sometimes though.